# VS2010 + Resharper 5 performance issues

Tags: performance, visual-studio-2010, resharper

I have been using VS2010 with Resharper 5 for several weeks and am having a performance issue. Sometimes when typing, the cursor will lag and the keystrokes won't show instantaneously. Also, scrolling will lag at times.

There is a [forum thread](http://www.jetbrains.net/devnet/message/5261640) started and JetBrains has been responding. Several people (including myself) have added their voice and uploaded some performance profiles.

If anyone here has has this issue, I would encourage you to visit the thread and let JetBrains know about it.

Has anyone had this problem and have a suggestion to restore performance?

Comment: uninstall it, it is way too heavy of a tool.

Comment: Ouch. You are right, it is a heavy tool. However, I feel that the benefits outweigh the cost. Until now. The typing drives me crazy. I'm living with it, but I really want it fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that 5.1.1 alleviates the problem that I was having.

Answer (score 4):

I played around a bit with the options, and things went much smoother after I disabled the ReSharper IntelliSense. I'm pretty sure that the IntelliSense was the culprit but as I said, I played around a bit before doing it so it may not be true.

And also, adding XAML documents to Skip Items list for the Code Analyzer made quite the big difference when editing XAML documents, which was a total pain before that, at least it felt like it did xP Sure it still is a little sluggish but not nearly as bad as it previously was.

Comment: Turning off Intellisense along with "Analyze errors in whole solution" (from the Code Inspection -> Settings tab) helped.

Answer (score 1):

By the way: the Resharper options are now by default the most efficient ones. I wanted to modify them as specified (especially : Turning off Intellisense along with "Analyze errors in whole solution") but was already properly configured. So must come either from:
The use of a later build, or automatic update from jetbrains